# How to display an element from a true or false inside Object? Javascript ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects, and I want to display the value from its status which is an attribute inside the object.

```js
this.state = {
  objetcs: [{
    value: 1,
    status: false
  }, {
    value: 2,
    status: true
  }]
}
}

// const object = [{ value: 1, status: false }, {value: 2, status: true} ]
```

If the status is true I render it, if not, not render.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most common pattern I see for conditional rendering in React, adapted for your particular structure:

```
this.state.objects.map(obj => (
  {obj.status && (
    <div>{obj.value}</div>
  )}
))
```

If you're doing this frequently, its easier to do this in a component:

```
const SomeObject = ({ state, value }) => {
  if (state) {
    return(
      <div>{value}</div>
    )
  } else {
    return null
  }
}
```

Or, if your component JSX is longer, extract a function:

```
class SomeObject extends React.PureComponent {
  renderObj = () => (
    <div>
      {this.props.value}
      Other HTML here
    </div>
  )

  render() {
    return this.props.state ? this.renderObj() : null
  }
}
```

This keeps the conditional logic out of your parent component and simplifies the JSX portion.

Answer (score 1):

make a separate component for easier working , and then send `status` and `value` as prop to component in your component have a if else

```
if(this.props.status)
     return //your render items
  else return null;
```